# Parsing a JSON response with special characters

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, special-characters

I'm currently parsing with javascript a JSON kind of string and I'm struggling with it.

I say JSON kind of string because this string is a response form a JSON Service, with the problem that every apex `"` is returned as `\"`.
I solved this with an elegant replace

```
string = string.replace("\\\"","\"")
```

and everything worked, till the moment I had to face an attribute whose value contained itself some `"`!

Let me explain with an example:

```
JSON response :
\"attr1\":\"value1\",
\"attr2\":\"value2\",
...
```

---

```
After my parsing :
"attr1":"value1",
"attr2":"value2",
...
```

And here everything is fine

Problem : when the response contains attributes like this :

```
JSON response :
\"attr1\":\"my name is \"Pippo\"\",
...
```

after my parsing I obviously get an error since the apex before the `P` ends the value!

```
"attr1":"my name is "Pippo"",
```

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+remove+special+charactor+from+json+string+in+javascript&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN1017IN1017&oq=how+to+remove+special+charactor+from+json+string+in+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l2.29864j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I do not have a JSON file to work on, I'm working on a string that seems a JSON..

Comment: Why does the service send it in this format? I'd either ask them to fix it so it can be parsed properly, or ask them how it is intended to be parsed. Because it is very unlikely that you are supposed to modify the string yourself before parsing.

Comment: Are you sure that those escape characters are actually there? They may be a artifact of debugging. How are you viewing the response? It may be worth adding a screenshot showing the content!

Comment: I perfectly agree, but even making the request with the header "contnt-Type" mapped as "application/json" does not give me the response parsed correctly

Comment: If you're looking at the response content via the browser console, you're probably being confused by it. Look at the "Network" developer tab, where you can see the actual response with no "helpful" formatting by the console.

Comment: The String `\`{ "attr1": "my name is \\"Pippo\\"" }\`` is valid JSON, and it contains exactly two backslashes; if you parse it and get the `"attr1"` property, the result will be the String `"my name is \"Pippo\""` which contains exactly zero backslashes. The String `\`{ "attr1": "my name is \"Pippo\"" }\`` is not valid JSON. Note that the String `"\""` contains exactly zero backslashes, and the String `"\\"` contains exactly one backslash.

Comment: Okay, silly me, it the service works. Thank you all